# Why does remotely accessing a file via a web page work with Apache 2.2 but not 2.4 even though I have updated files required by 2.4?

Tags: apache-httpd

I'm migrating from Apache 2.2 to 2.4 and can no longer access files that are not in document root -- a classic alias problem. I have read many conflicting posts about this and made changes recommended by the official Apache doc regarding the use of alias, but it's still not working. I have set logging levels to the most verbose, namely debug in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf and /etc/apache2.conf to try to solve the problem.

I have a web page that tries to access foo.txt on /var/tmp on each of two machines. I can access it just fine using 2.2 but I get an error, The requested URL was not found on this server, with 2.4. I'm using an alias in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.conf on 2.2 and 000-default.conf on 2.4, to access that folder, and I've defined that folder in a directory block.

I'm using this in 2.4's 000-default.conf:

'''
<VirtualHost *:8000>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/tmp/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </Directory>
    Alias /Dummy/ /var/tmp/
    LogLevel debug
```

'''

I thought the problem might be permissions since it is often an issue. On the 2.2 machine, I have just root root on the folder and it works fine (ls -all -d /var/tmp):

drwxrwxrwt 6 root root 2200 Oct 24 16:41 /var/tmp

and (ls -all /var/tmp/foo.txt):

-rw-r--r--  1 root root     805 Oct 24 16:42 foo.txt

to the file I'm trying to access in that folder.

Since that didn't work on the machine with 2.4, I tried this for the folder:

drwxrwxrwt 9 www-data www-data 1440 Oct 24 16:44 /var/tmp

and this on the file that I'm trying to access in that folder:

-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data     836 Oct 24 16:45 foo.txt

The first example works fine with 2.2 but the second example fails with 2.4, giving me:

Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server.

In /var/log/apache2/access.log I get:

IP address - - [24/Oct/2020:16:47:02 -0400] "GET /Dummy/foo.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 497 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"

In /var/log/apache2/error.log I get:

'''
[Sat Oct 24 16:52:01.154485 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 32675] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client IP address:34306] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted

[Sat Oct 24 16:52:01.155003 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 32675] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client IP address:34306] AH01626: authorization result of : granted

[Sat Oct 24 16:52:01.155659 2020] [core:info] [pid 32675] [client IP address:34306] AH00128: File does not exist: /var/tmp/foo.txt
'''

The URL I'm using is:

http://IPaddress:8000/Dummy/foo.txt

I tried leaving the trailing / off the alias, and I got a permission error instead of not found, so I restored the trailing /. I restarted apache2 after each change to a config file.

Yes, the target file is really there. I have not touched the default .htaccess file.

How can I fix this ???

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are not only changing to apache 2.4 but that apache 2.4 is run by systemd and the apache2.service systemd file contains `PrivateTmp=true` Which means, it will have its own `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` separate from the system (see [SYSTEMD.EXEC(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#PrivateTmp=)).

The `/var/tmp` seen by apache will actually live at `/var/tmp/systemd-private-<long hash>-apache2.service-f00WPn/tmp`

The solution is to either disable that directive or to place the files at a different folder. If the files are created by another daemon, you could use `JoinsNamespaceOf=` directive to have both share the same `/tmp` and `/var/tmp`

Comment: Thank you. I found the apache2 systemd file in /lib and copied it to the /etc/systemd/system folder. I set PrivateTmp=False and restarted both apache2 and the apache2 service. But I still get Not Found when I try to access files in /var/tmp. I have other aliases that point to other folders, and they work, so my basic setup is ok. I don't understand how to make the other change you mentioned. How do I fix this ?

Comment: @NewtownGuy did you copy it on the right place? I have /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache2.service being a symlink to /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service so if you copied it somewhere else, an entry like that could still be in effect. Also, you will need `systemctl daemon-reload` to ensure the change of the unit file takes effect.

Comment: Yes. I copied /lib/systemd/service/apache2.service to /etc/systemd/service and edited it there. Other than rebooting, is there another way to do daemon-reload ? I have current Buster OS with latest updates, but I don't have the systemctl command and cannot find it with apt-get.